# How to detect french toxic comments with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am developing a chat application in French and I want to block a certain type of message (of a sexual nature for example)
Ideally a js api would help me out, I've explored tensorflow.js which looks fine to me but unless I misconfigured, it only considers English sentences. If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the Google API called Perspective https://perspectiveapi.com which takes into consideration several languages and is very easy to use.
it might help someone else...